# HMMs: How to Interpret The Average Likelihood Of My Data

Tags: machine-learning, likelihood, hidden-markov-model

I have recently trained an HMM using R's depmixS4 package, and am evaluating its performance via the average likelihood of my data. The equation is provided below:
[image]

However, I noticed the average likelihoods my model is attributing to the  data are extremely low. For example, I'm passing in observation sequences and receiving values like '3.28295e-09'.

Does this mean my model is extremely poorly fitted? I would understand if this was the raw likelihood, as long sequences would have a lower probability of appearing, but I am already computing an average value here. Any guidance would be appreciated.